# removing css of specific DIV When listing of all classes is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found the following code from stackoverflow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var allTags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
var classNames = {};
for (var tg = 0; tg< allTags.length; tg++) {
    var tag = allTags[tg];
    if (tag.className) {
     var classes = tag.className.split(" ");
     for (var cn = 0; cn < classes.length; cn++){
     var cName = classes[cn];
     if (! classNames[cName]) 
         {
       classNames[cName] = true;
     }
   }
    }   
}
var classList = [];
for (var name in classNames) 
    classList.push(name+'<br />');
document.getElementById('allclasses').innerHTML = classList.sort();
</script>
```

The above works awesome but just for classes, what about ID's
Now there is one scenario that with the div like this:

```
<div class="head">
   internal divs having classes, IDs should be ignored --
</div> 

<div class="footer">
   internal divs having classes, IDs should be ignored --
</div>
```

How can i make above changes to the code, I am asking because I am dumb in Javascript, and i need to make it work as task given..

Comment: Do you want a jQuery solution (much shorter), or is that `jquery` tag an accident?

Comment: if jquery is a solution, i would love too

Comment: Yes, it is checking all html elements which has associated classes and adding them in the end in a kind of list

Comment: and you want a list of id's too? Not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just wanted a list if IDs, like your class list, there is a jQuery version.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/LXhtr/

ID Version in jQuery:

```
var ids = {};
$('[id]').each(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    ids[id] = id;
});
var idList = [];
for (var id in ids) {
    idList.push(id + '<br />');
}
$('#allids').html(idList.sort());
```

Notes:

`$('[id]')` is a jQuery selector that returns any element with an id. `$('[class]')` does the same for any elements with classes. As you can see jQuery is a lot leaner than raw JavaScript. There is still scope to make these even shorter if required, but that would move so far from your existing code you might not recognize anything :)

### Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/LXhtr/3/

You wanted to exclude anything within a `class="header"` or `class="footer"`.

You can do this in jQuery with selectors like `:not([class=header]):not([class=header] *)` which basically says, do not include this match, or anything beneath this match.

```
var ids = {};
$('[id]:not([class=header]):not([class=footer]):not([class=header] *):not([class=footer] *)').each(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    ids[id] = id;
});
var idList = [];
for (var id in ids) {
    idList.push(id + ' <br/>');
}
$('#allids ').html(idList.sort());
```

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie, But what about the second portion of the code if i need to not to include the header & footer in the searched ID's and Classes, Like this one which is included in the above question         `<div class="head">
   internal divs having classes, IDs should be ignored --
</div> 

<div class="footer">
   internal divs having classes, IDs should be ignored --
</div>`

Comment: @odd_even_algorithm: Even with your new comment, I still do not understand that part of the question. Can you explain it in a different way? Possibly with an example of the expected result?

Comment: That looks like you just want the jQuery `text()` method to fetch the inner text? What do you want extracted?

Comment: i want not to include **head** and **footer** div and any content inside it, that's all

Comment: @odd_even_algorithm: Added the appropriate filters and tried to explain how they work.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it fully, but testing it right now, if i come up with someting, can i ask again

Comment: @odd_even_algorithm: Sure, just ask another question. If you provide a JSFiddle with it you will get more/faster responses. Thanks